# How do I prove that the cosine of vectors v and w will always be $-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } $ if $x+y+z=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given that $x+y+z=0$ and the vectors $\overrightarrow { v } =(x,y,z)$ and  $\overrightarrow { w } =(z,x,y)$

How do I prove that $\frac { \overrightarrow { v } \cdot \overrightarrow { w }  }{ \left\| \overrightarrow { v }  \right\| \left\| \overrightarrow { w }  \right\|  } $ will always be equal to $-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } $

Steps I took:

$$\overrightarrow { v } \cdot \overrightarrow { w } \Rightarrow \begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{matrix}\cdot \begin{matrix} z \\ x \\ y \end{matrix}\Rightarrow xz+yz+zy$$

$$\left\| \overrightarrow { v }  \right\| =\sqrt { x^{ 2 }+y^{ 2 }+z^{ 2 } } \quad and\quad \left\| \overrightarrow { w }  \right\| =\sqrt { z^{ 2 }+x^{ 2 }+y^{ 2 } } $$

$$\frac { \overrightarrow { v } \cdot \overrightarrow { w }  }{ \left\| \overrightarrow { v }  \right\| \left\| \overrightarrow { w }  \right\|  } =\frac { xz+yx+zy }{ \sqrt { x^{ 2 }+y^{ 2 }+z^{ 2 } } \sqrt { z^{ 2 }+x^{ 2 }+y^{ 2 } }  } \Rightarrow \frac { xz+yx+zy }{ x^{ 2 }+y^{ 2 }+z^{ 2 } } $$

Where am I going wrong? Or how can I arrive at the solution from here if I am going about this the right way.

Hints only, please. No actual solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2yz+2zx$ . What is x+y+z?

Comment: I don't get where I made the mistake